# CIFS Mount issue - Unable to write

Tags: cifs

After doing the cifs mount we are unable to touch on the share with the user kvk. But we are able to do the same as a root user. following are the configuration and error log.

Fedora version 15:
fstab:

```
//<windows-ip>/HS        /home/kvk/share/HS      cifs   defaults,username=user_support   0           0
```

Error while touch :

```
[kvk@ats-079 @temp]$ pwd
/home/kvk/share/HS/temp
[kvk@ats-079 @temp]$ touch newfile
touch: cannot touch `newfile': Permission denied
```

@temp is the directory with in  //windows-ip>/HS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
//<windows-ip>/HS    /home/kvk/share/HS    cifs    uid=kvk,gid=kvk,file_mode=0664,dir_mode=0775   0 0
```

Comment: This should possibly fix the problem on the linux/unix side. The other topic are acls on the server side for user `user_support`. The best check for that is to test the share with `smbclient //<windows-ip>/HS`